# notepad++ user defined language delimiter only at the beginning of a line

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I want to set a user defined language syntax that includes a rule for strings that are bounded by square brackets.  However, I don't want ALL square bracket bounded strings to be colored, only those that are the first non-whitespace character on a line.

For example:

```
[COLORED] Random stuff here
Random stuff [NOT COLORED]
  [COLORED] Random stuff
```

Can this be done with the dialog?  I have the a delimeter set as below, but nothing I add to the escape box, nor any changes to the open box, get me what I want.

[image]